# How to make a thread working in the background upon IIS server even without any request to the web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, iis, asp.net-web-api, scheduled-tasks

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application deployed on IIS server,

In that app, I do a thing such like below in a independent thread:

```
while (true)
{
    doSomeJobs();
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
}
```

Start this thread in `Application_Start()`
so seems it will never stop only sleep for 5 minutes between every round of job.

First looks work well but in the next day I check the log it's not working as I expect, it's been stopped working for a very long time.

**Then when I send a request again to the app, it begins to work again.**

So what did I miss up? Is it possible to make a thread working in the background in every specific time even without any request to the app? Such like a scheduled task ?

Comment: Not sure what you are exact use case is. But it sounds like the need of an always running service (Windows service)

Comment: @Shyju yes, How could I do that?

Comment: If you want a scheduled task, Windows allows you to create directly, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx. If you want more control over how the code runs, you can create a Windows service app, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer Don't bother IIS/ASP.NET, as they are not designed for your goals.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found this a common issue,

That's because IIS will stop your process in the specific time if nobody requests to your app.

To keep your app alive.

1. Create a new application pool which needs to host always-alive app.
2. Choose that application pool and click advanced setting.

[image]

3. under **recycling** set **Regular time interval** to **0**

[image]

4. under **process model** set **idle timeout (minute)** to the max (43200)

[image]